# Why is the output of this code fffffff9?

Tags: c++

```
int main(){
    char c=0371;
    cout<<hex<<(int) c;
 return 0;
}
```

I converted *c* into binary system(011 111 001) then hexadecimal (f9). Then why does it give the result fffffff9 not f9?

Comment: Your 8-bit `char` is **signed** and is being **sign-extended** to a 32-bit **signed** `int` before it is output to the console.  Since its initial value has its high bit set to 1, so do the extra bits

Comment: The cast to int is sign extending.

Comment: `char` may or may not be signed. `0371` will not fit in an `signed char`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default

Comment: @vsoftco: Yes, that leading zero is a common issue. :-(

Comment: You are using an octal literal for some reason, its value is 11111001.  A negative value, it gets sign-extended to 1111....11111001.  Which is ffffff9 in hex.  Maybe you didn't really intend to use octal.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: `0371` is not the same as `0x371`,

Answer (score 4):

If the `char` type on your system is signed, the value 0xf9 is a negative number (specifically, it’s -7). As a result, when you convert it to an integer, it gives the integer the numeric value -7, which has hexadecimal representation 0xFFFFFFF9 (if you’re using signed 32-bit integer representations).

If you explicitly make your character value an `unsigned char`, then C++ will cast it as though it has the positive value 249, which has equivalent integer value 249 with hexadecimal representation 0x000000F9.